# How to enable <C-k> to "scroll up" in code sugguestions/hints with vscode vim instead of using arrow keys?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

VScodevim has `extension.vim_ctrl+j` by default mapped to Ctrl+j which allows you do navigate **down** pop-up code suggestion windows (triggered by hitting Ctrl+Space in insert mode) like this:

[image]

It also has `extension.vim_ctrl+k` mapped to Ctrl+k but this binding down not work, so I cannot scroll **up** pop-up code suggestion windows.  in insert mode defaults to entering a [digraph](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html) but simply adding something like this

```
    {
      "before": ["<C-k>"],
      "after": ["extension.vim_ctrl+k"]
    }
```

to my `settings.json` does not work since although it removes the digraph functionality, from what I understand, whenever I now press Ctrl+k in insert mode, VSCode will consult the `settings.json`, find the mapping of  to "extension.vim_ctrl+k" which points it back to `settings.json` in a sort of infinite loop.

`:h i_ctrl-j` in vim reveals this keybind to be mapped to "Begin new line" so it seems VScode interprets "Begin new line" as navigating **down** a pop-up window in insert mode instead of it's usual vim behaviour of creating a new line and moving the cursor there, although not sure this is how it works. In any case, I could not find an equivalent vim command that perhaps VSCode could use to scroll up in pop-up windows. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I got this working by copying the existing default keybinds for `ctrl+p` and `ctrl+n` which are used throughout VSCode by default for scrolling up and down.

I've used `alt` here in my `keybinds.json` file but you can easily replace it with `ctrl` to achieve what you want

**keybinds.json**

```json
// Down Motion
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "cursorDown",
  "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "showNextParameterHint",
  "when": "editorFocus && parameterHintsMultipleSignatures && parameterHintsVisible"
},
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "list.focusDown",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},

// Up Motion
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "cursorUp",
  "when": "textInputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "showPrevParameterHint",
  "when": "editorFocus && parameterHintsMultipleSignatures && parameterHintsVisible"
},
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "list.focusUp",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
}
```